# Is head-tail printing more efficient than checking for end or beginning?

Tags: c++, list, loops, c++11, lambda

So I have a list. I want to print all the elements in that list separated by spaces.

The first thing that comes to my head is doing,

```
for (auto& ele : somelist)
{
  cout << ele << ' ';
}
```

or,

```
for (auto& ele : somelist)
{
  cout << ' ' << ele;
}
```

The problem is that is introduces an extra space.

A way to handle that extra space, then, is with a conditional.

```
for (int idx{}; idx < somelist.size(); ++idx)
{
  if (idx == 0)
    cout << somelist[idx];

  else
    cout << ' ' << somelist[idx];
}
```

or,

```
for (int idx{}; idx < somelist.size(); ++idx)
{
  if (idx == somelist.size() - 1)
    cout << somelist[idx];

  else
    cout << somelist[idx] << ' ';
}
```

But something about having a condition that will be true only once bothers me. I came up with my own way to print a list using lambdas to manage if an extra space is inserted or not without checking every iteration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto printHead = [] (int num)
    {
      std::cout << num;
    };

  auto printTail = [] (int num)
    {
      std::cout << ' ' << num;
    };

  // Need explicit type for lambda if its going to be captured
  std::function<void(int)> print = [&printHead, &printTail, &print] (int num)
    {
      printHead(num);
      print = printTail;
    };

  for (auto& element : {1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,6})
  {
    print(element);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Would it be reasonable to assume that this solution is more efficient, performance-wise, than the original conditional version?

Comment: Given the overhead of using `std::function`, probably not. Branch prediction is pretty good these days. That being said, I/O time is going to absolutely dominate here, and it's really not worth worrying about micro-optimisations like this at all.

Comment: Right. And given an even larger list, big enough for the overhead of `std::function` to be mitigated, it only gives branch prediction more reason to believe that the condition will not hold for the majority of cases.

Comment: @Yuushi Just to be clear, is the only thing stopping this from working efficiently `std::function`? If I managed to do it without using it, would it work?

Comment: Potentially. Is there any reason you're so worried about the overhead here?

Comment: Not really. I just wanted to know if there was overhead incurred by assigning lambdas around. I thought `print = printTail` would incur extra overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting the conditional outside of the loop?

```
if (!somelist.empty()) std::cout << somelist[0];
for (int i = 1; i < somelist.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << ' ' << somelist[i];
}
```

**Edit**: I didn't answer the actual question. Let's compare:

Method 1 (~243 instructions):

```
std::vector<int> somelist = {1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,6};
for (int idx{}; idx < somelist.size(); ++idx)
{
    if (idx == 0)
        std::cout << somelist[idx];

    else
        std::cout << ' ' << somelist[idx];
}
```

Method 2 (~555 instructions):

```
auto printHead = [] (int num)
    {
        std::cout << num;
    };

auto printTail = [] (int num)
    {
        std::cout << ' ' << num;
    };

// Need explicit type for lambda if its going to be captured
std::function<void(int)> print = [&printHead, &printTail, &print] (int num)
    {
        printHead(num);
        print = printTail;
    };

std::vector<int> somelist = {1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,6};
for (auto& element : somelist)
{
    print(element);
}
```

Method 3 (~240 instructions):

```
std::vector<int> somelist = {1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,6};

if (!somelist.empty()) std::cout << somelist[0];
for (int i = 1; i < somelist.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << ' ' << somelist[i];
}
```

These were all compiled with clang++ 3.3 on OS X, with `-Ofast -flto`. While processors are complex beasts, and it's hard to say which version is fastest (across all CPUs), I'd argue that method #3 is probably fastest (based on instruction count), followed by a close method #1, and followed by method #2. It looks like your proposed method prevents a lot of compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "**[Loop and a Half](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Loops/N_plus_one_half%E2%80%8E)**" construct (I'm not sure if I count instructions the same as @Cornstalks , but `gcc -S -o -` gives 153 lines of assembly):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    auto somelist = std::vector<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,6};

    auto first = begin(somelist), last = end(somelist);
    if (first != last) {                // initial check
        while (true) {
            std::cout << *first++;     
            if (first == last) break;   // check in the middle
            std::cout << ", ";
        }
    }
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9087e72a92c321c6) that prints

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6

i.e. without a separator at the end of the last element (I'm using ", " as separator because it's easier to spot than a space, adjust to your wishes of course).

The "check in the middle" is what makes this different than a range-for, a `while` or `do-while` loop. It also splits a lambda to `std::for_each` in two which suggests a pretty generic version that generalizes `std::for_each` to a loop taking two lambdas, one before and one after the check:

```
template<class It, class UnaryOp1, class UnaryOp2>
void loop_and_a_half(It first, It last, UnaryOp1 op1, UnaryOp2 op2)
{
    if (first == last) return;
    while (true) {
        op1(*first++);
        if (first == last) break;
        op2(*first);
    }    
}
```

that can be called like this (using C++14 generic lambdas):

```
loop_and_a_half(
    begin(somelist), end(somelist),
    [](auto e) { std::cout << e; },
    [](auto) { std::cout << ", "; }
);
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05c4885f1269bf6e) that prints the same output.

Comment: Nice, nifty alternative. FYI, I was approximating instruction count by doing `otool -tv executable_name | wc -l` (which, with your code, is ~228 instructions on my system).

Comment: Ah nice, didn't know about that tool.

Answer (score 2):

How about a simpler solution that doesn't involve `std::function`?

```
char space = '\0';
for (auto& ele : somelist)
{
  cout << space << ele;
  space = ' ';
}
```

Or you could use iterators

```
auto first = somelist.cbegin();
auto last = somelist.cend();

if(first != last) {
  cout << *first++;
}
for(; first != last; ++first) {
  cout << ' ' << *first;
}
```

---

`std::function` uses type erasure, most likely via virtual functions, to dispatch the call to the target function; this will involve some overhead. To determine if it's any faster / slower than the other examples you're just going to have to measure it.

Comment: Regarding the second implementation, I would move the `first++` into the initialiser of the _for_ loop, and move the _for_ loop into the block of the _if_ statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement the '<<' operator for both the list and the elements of the list.

- The '<<' for the list would take care to just iterate over all the elements
- The '<<' for each element would take care to print it out with the correct amount of spaces.

This would reduce your original code to just being :

```
cout << somelist;
```

Comment: And yet, when implementing a custom `<<` operator, he'd still have to do what he's doing in his question...

Comment: Right, but it seemed like the complication with OP's current code is that there's that ugly condition check to handle printing the last element. 

That could possibly be abstracted away more cleanly by an OOP approach, I thought.